# Mutable array is automatically changed to immutable, while adding the object to it. why?

Tags: objective-c, copy, nsmutablearray, memory-leaks

These are setter and getters.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)contactList
{
    return contactList;
}
-(void)setContactList:(NSMutableArray*) aContactList
{
    [contactList release];
    contactList=aContactList; //its working fine but leaks 
    // contactList=[aContactList copy]; 
    //   If I keep like this getting exception as mutating 
    //   object setting to immutable but it is mutable only. 
}
```

In view controller, in edit functionality, I am adding new object to the list like this

```
[tempDetailsObj.contactList addObject:editcontacts];
```

here I am getting exception as mutating

object setting to immutable but it is mutable only.

If I remove copy its working fine but I am getting Leak, So I want to add the object to the list without any exception and it should not produce any leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you are not taking ownership of the parameters passed to your setter. Also you'll want to copy mutable instances to avoid them being changed under you.

Use e.g. this:

```
- (void)setContactList:(NSMutableArray *)aContactList {
    NSMutableArray *tmp = contactList;
    contactList = [aContactList mutableCopy];
    [tmp release];
}
```

But then, why not use just use declared properties:

```
// interface:
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *contactList;

// implementation:
@synthesize contactList;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either try `-mutableCopy` or just using the already existing reference with `-removeAllObjects`:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)contactList
{
    return contactList;
}
-(void)setContactList:(NSMutableArray*) aContactList
{
    //   Either this way:
    [contactList removeAllObjects];
    [contactList addObjectsFromArray:aContactList];
    //   Or this way:
    [contactList release];
    contactList = [aContactList mutableCopy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether it solves the problem, but try out the following

instead of

```
 [contactList release]; contactList=aContactList;
```

try recyling the old reference

```
[contactList removeAllObjects]; [contactList addObjectsFromArray:aContactList];
```

regards